# Multiple website JS and JS issues

Tags: magento2.2

I have created multiple websites .Main website worked perfectly but second website has the following issues seen in console:

```
CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Above error mainly occurs when you try to access the resources from a different domain. So in your case the second website must be trying to load the resources from the main Website.

You can allow the resources to load on the second website using :

> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "b.com"

or you can also use

> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

This will allow the resources to load on all domains.

On another thought if your website uses different locale try to find if the static content for the locale is deployed correctly or not.

Let me know if it helps.

Sunil

Comment: I have added" Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" "in main .htacess file   but not working

Comment: also have to tried if the static content is deployed correctly ? can i have the link where you are facing this issue ?